# Fetching array of contacts from ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion() gives nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

I am trying to print out all of my phone's contacts to the console, using `NSLog()`. Currently this code is just printing `(null)`.

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *contactsObjects;
```

**.m**

```
@synthesize contactsObjects;
//lazy instantiation. 
- (NSMutableArray *)contactsObjects
{
    if(!contactsObjects)
    {
        contactsObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    return contactsObjects;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CFErrorRef error = nil;

    // Request authorization to Address Book
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if (granted) {
                // First time access has been granted, add all the user's contacts to array.
                CFMutableArrayRef contactsObjects = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);
            } else {
                // User denied access.
                // Display an alert telling user that they must allow access to proceed to the "invites" page.
            }
        });
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // The user has previously given access, add all the user's contacts to array.
        CFMutableArrayRef contactsObjects = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);
    }
    else {
        // The user has previously denied access
        // Send an alert telling user that they must allow access to proceed to the "invites" page.
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", contactsObjects);
}
```

I get two warnings here:

[image]

I have no idea what I am supposed to do in order to properly print  the names and numbers of my contacts to the console.

How do I print my contacts names and numbers?

Comment: Don't you have another warning in `viewWillAppear:` about shadowing an ivar? Or an error about an undeclared variable pointing at the setter?

Comment: I don't actually. The two errors a "yellow !" errors, and they're just for the error I posted above.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you on? Are you explicitly synthesizing `contactsObjects`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the explicit synthesization is, but I have synth'd it:  `@synthesize contactsObjects;`

Comment: That's explicit synthesis, yup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scope problem with your code. The `contactsObjects` variables in `viewWillAppear:` are not related to the ivar you have called `contactsObjects`. You're declaring new variables that are using the same name. The `NSLog()` at the end, on the other hand, is the ivar. But setting those other variables didn't put anything into the ivar, so you see `(null)`, which is how `NSLog()` represents "no object".

Fix this by not making new variable declarations, but using the ivar.

```
if (granted) {
    contactsObjects = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);

else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    contactsObjects = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);
```

You will also need to cast these:

```
    contactsObjects = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);
```

(Also, the function doesn't return a mutable array, so you may have trouble down the road with that.)

The second problem is that `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion()` doesn't stop and wait for its completion Block to run. While access is being requested, the rest of your method carries on, so you reach the `NSLog()` before `contactsObjects` is actually set in that case.

Comment: Ok so, using the `(__bridge_transfer NSArray *)` gives me a warning for 'incompatible' pointer type', so I need to redeclare the variable **contactsObjects** as an `NSArray` rather than an `NSMutableArray`? And your suggesting that I need a breakpoint after the `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion()` method? Also, (__bridge NSMutableArray *) was not causing any warnings, but it was causing the console to print out addresses rather than names or #'s

Comment: Yes, change the property's type. Casting to `NSMutableArray` is a lie. It doesn't change the mutability of the array. You don't need a breakpoint. Breakpoints are for debugging. You just need to take into account the fact that, when you request access, `contactObjects` won't be set until after the completion Block runs, which may or may not be before `viewWillAppear:` ends.

Answer (score 2):

You say it prints out null and that you get an error. But this would explain your error.

`contactObjects` is defined within the if block and the else if block. So by the time you are outside of your conditional it's no longer defined.

Try this

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CFErrorRef error = nil;

    // Request authorization to Address Book
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if (granted) {
                // First time access has been granted, add all the user's contacts to array.
                contactsObjects = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);
            } else {
                // User denied access.
                // Display an alert telling user that they must allow access to proceed to the "invites" page.
            }
        });
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // The user has previously given access, add all the user's contacts to array.
        contactsObjects = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);
    }
    else {
        // The user has previously denied access
        // Send an alert telling user that they must allow access to proceed to the "invites" page.
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", contactsObjects);
}
```

Comment: `contactsObjects` almost certainly shouldn't be locally declared here; I'm pretty sure OP just wants to put it into the ivar. Other than that this is it.

Comment: I'm sorry, must be blind to my own mistake, but I do not even see a change in your code and mine. Do you mind pointing out where exactly you made change?

Comment: Yeah, as @JoshCaswell mentioned, you would probably put this outside of the function (or as a return value) but this was the easiest way to explain the error.

Comment: That actually just caused another error. With `CFMutableArrayRef contactsObjects;` added, it is suggesting that I set the variable to NULL, to look like `CFMutableArrayRef contactsObjects = NULL;` Without or with the NULL initiating, the errors still exist.

Comment: There's no return value from `viewWillAppear:` (Also, note that it's a warning, not an error.) Just delete the local declaration `CFMutableArrayRef contactsObjects;` Then the two references to `contactsObjects` in `viewWillAppear:` are the ivar, which is what you're trying to do, @WhiteHatPrince.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I see, removed the declaration from my answer.

Comment: The warnings still exist. In your answer, are you also suggesting that I delete the lazy instantiation code? Ill post a picture.

Comment: What warnings exactly are you seeing?  I don't think you need to remove the lazy instantiation code.

Comment: The photo was just posted.. sorry for it's size

Comment: Remove the `CFMutableArrayRef` from both lines (like in my example).  You do not want to declare a new CFMutableArrayRef, but use the one that already exists in your class, like you are doing on your lazy instantiation code.

Comment: Ohhh, my bad man I really could not see it. Took it out and it wanted a bridge. Gave it the bridge and I'm trying it right now